# How do i restrict my sign up to people with a specific email domain in PHP

Tags: php, email-validation

How do i restrict my sign up to people with a specific email domain in PHP

So for example, only people with a '@amn.com' email address can register

Comment: On your registration form, implement a client-side check that would only submit the form if the input matches your criteria. And when the user submits the form, grab the value from the form (using the respective `name` attribute in the `$_POST` array) and compare the string to see if it matches the said domain name - if it does, fail with appropriate error message; if not, continue.

Comment: That said, next time you ask a question, please make sure you include all the relevant code and your attempts so far to tackle the problem. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking for code. Just a pure english explaination

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression:

```
<?php
$email = "mytestemail@amn.com";
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Not a valid e-mail address!");
} else {
    if(empty(preg_match("/@amn.com$/", $email))) {
        die("E-mail must end with @amn.com!");
    } else {
        //valid//
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$domain = explode('@',$email)[1];

if($domain != 'amn.com')
{
    die('This domain is not allowed to register')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your server, check the mail input field if it contains the string and ends with it, like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$domain = explode('@',$email)[1];
$emailErr = '';
$domain = explode('@',$email)[1];
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || $domain != 'amn.com') {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email"; 
} else {
    //valid - use input
}
```

For js validation, you can use something like this:

```
function validateEmail(email)
{
    var splitted = email.match("^(.+)@thisdomainonly\.com$");
    if (splitted == null) return false;
    if (splitted[1] != null)
    {
        var regexp_user = /^\"?[\w-_\.]*\"?$/;
        if (splitted[1].match(regexp_user) == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```